# How can I use .updateData() instead of .setData() in flutter firestore even when document does not exist

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to do something along the lines that, if there does not exist a document then do setData and if the document exist, do update data... I have tried this(the code below), it seems to work but I am concerned that what if when I launch the app and the error message changes.

```
Future updateReference(
    String phoneNumber,
  ) async {
    try {
      return await mCollectionRef.document(phoneNumber).updateData({
        uid: true,
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (error) {
      print(error.message.substring(0, 9));
      if (error.message.substring(0, 9) == 'NOT_FOUND') {
        return await mCollectionRef.document(phoneNumber).setData({
          uid: true,
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Is there any other way in which I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update or create a document if it doesn't already exist, you can just pass `merge: true` as the second argument to [setData()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/setData.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response, ill try that asap.

Comment: is there any point of using updateData() over setData() with merge set to true?

Comment: updateData will fail if the document doesn't exist, and setData will *not* fail if the document doesn't exist. You can choose which behavior is more useful to you.